# GET response of query SQL in ORACLE using PHP

Tags: php, oracle

From console ORACLE:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE STACKOVERFLOW (c01 varchar2(30));
Table created.

SQL> DROP TABLE STACKOVERFLOW;
Table dropped.
```

How I can take this RESPONSES from ORACLE using PHP???

The function:

```
oci_execute($QUERY)
```

only return true.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you will not be able to do that. Messages about which you are asking are not coming directly from the DB engine, but from DB client, the Oracle console. Console asks the engine for executing your query, sees the answer from engine (true/false), checks what you asked for, and display proper message.

Comment: no is only this 2 commands, exist severals commands where is required get the answer from ORACLE: 

grant create session to administrador;
RESPONSE = Grant succeeded

Comment: It looks like in OCI this could be partially done with [`OCIStmtPrepare` and then `OCIAttrGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci04sql.htm#i429200).  Although that still wouldn't be quite as granular as you wanted; it would only tell you that it's a DROP statement and not return "Table dropped.".  I think you're looking for the SQL*Plus "feedback message".  I have created an [open-source program](https://github.com/jonheller1/plsql_lexer/blob/master/packages/statement_feedback.plsql) to do that in PL/SQL.  But I'd only recommend that if there's no client solution.